autoplay not working on Safari on iphone only
Suddenly, my videos are not autoplaying in Safari on iphone. I am not seeing any error messages. Is this a "feature" of Safari on iphone now? Do I need to require users to click play to view background videos? All works fine on Safari on mac desktop, and on Firefox and Chrome on iphone.
This code has always worked on Safari/iphone in the past, so I'm confused why it's not working now.
I've also viewed the other posts about this problem but haven't seen a solution that fixes my issue.
<video muted playsinline autoplay loop style="width: 500px;" preload="auto" >
     <source src="https://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/.test/video/Dumplings3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>


The problem was the video itself. I created it as a clip of a larger video using a free online tool. Whatever that tool was, it did something to the video that Safari on iphone and only Safari on iphone did not like.

So the modified (by online tool) video did not respond to autoplay but it would still work anyways if the play button was manually pressed? Strange quirk. All I noticed about it is that the MP4 has EXIF metadata added (title, description, etc).

@VC.One I didn't try anything with the controls.

It's likely that your edited video contained an audio track, and the original didn't.
Autoplay policies are mostly concerned with audio.  While background video can be limited by throttling/power saving, that probably isn't the issue here since simply changing out the video file "fixed" it.
So, your editor probably added a default empty audio track.  Hard to say for sure since you didn't provide an example video and deleted whatever was at that URL already...
